# Conservation of classical currents in an interacting fermionic model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem, quantum-anomalies, bosonization

I have a system of massless fermions described by

\begin{equation}
Z = \int {\cal D}\psi {\cal D} \overline{\psi} e^{S_{\alpha}} 
\end{equation}
where $S_{\alpha} = \int d^{2}x [i\overline{ \psi}  \gamma^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}\psi - \frac{\alpha^2}{2} j^{\mu}j_{\mu}]$ with $j^{\mu}=\overline{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} \psi $. Using the Hubbard-Stratonovich identity, $Z$ can be rewritten as
\begin{equation}
Z = \int {\cal D}\psi {\cal D} \overline{\psi} e^{S_{\alpha}} =\int {\cal D}\psi {\cal D} \overline{\psi} e^{S_{b}} 
\end{equation}
where
$S_{b} = \int d^{2}x [i \overline{ \psi}  \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu} -i \alpha b_{\mu} )\psi + \frac{1}{2} b^{\mu}b_{\mu}]$.

Acting the Euler-Lagrange equation on $S_{b}$, I can calculate the equation of motions for spinors and show that the classical vector current is conserved as $\partial_{\mu} (\overline{ \psi}  \gamma^{\mu}  \psi)=0$.

However, taking similar steps on $S_{\alpha}$ gives me

\begin{equation}
[- \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \overline{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} j_{\mu} - \frac{\alpha^2}{2} j^{\mu} \overline{\psi} \gamma_{\mu} ]\psi -[i (\partial_{\mu} \overline{ \psi} ) \gamma^{\mu} ] \psi =0,
\Rightarrow
i (\partial_{\mu} \overline{ \psi} ) \gamma^{\mu}  \psi +\frac{\alpha^2}{2} [ \overline{\psi} \gamma^{\mu} j_{\mu} \psi + j^{\mu} j_{\mu} ]  =0,
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\overline{ \psi} i \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu}\psi) - \frac{\alpha^2}{2} \overline{ \psi} [\gamma^{\mu} \psi j_{\mu} + j^{\mu} \gamma_{\mu} \psi]=0,
\Rightarrow
\overline{ \psi} i \gamma^{\mu} (\partial_{\mu}\psi) - \frac{\alpha^2}{2}  [j^{\mu}  j_{\mu} + \overline{ \psi} j^{\mu} \gamma_{\mu} \psi]=0.
\end{equation}

The summation of the last two equations, however, does not result in $\partial_{\mu} (\overline{ \psi}  \gamma^{\mu}  \psi)=0$, as opposed to what I have obtained from $S_{b}$.

I assume the classical currents for both actions should be conserved.
Hence, my question is how I can simplify the above two equations to obtain conservation equations from the interacting action.